# Returning generated markup from CS Helper file via jQuery/AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, razor, webmatrix

I have some markup that I am generating in a Helper file (which is located in the root\App_Code\myHelper.cs directory):

```
@helper GenerateMarkup(int id)
{
   <div class="dude">
      <a href="awesome.cshtml">Wow</a>
   </div>
}
```

and, in my results page, I have a place where this is supposed to go. It's supposed to go inside a Container `div`:

```
<div class="ContainerDIV">

</div>
```

I made a little jQuery to try and send an ID (`int`) to the `GenerateMarkup(int id)` method inside the Helper file, which should return the generated markup back to the jQuery function, which, in turn, should display the generated markup inside the `ContainerDIV`, mentioned above.

Here's my jQuery stuff (which is inside the `ContainerDIV`'s div (please excuse the sucky-ness of my jQuery, I'm quite new to it):

```
    <div id="ContainerDIV" class="Bordered">
        <script>
                $('.MoreInformationOnPosition').click(function () {
                    var elID = $(this).attr('id');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "JTS.cs/GenerateMarkup",
                        data: elID,
                        contentType: "application/html",
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                            $("#ContainerDIV").attr(msg.d);
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </div>
```

It's just not working. I've tried PageInspecter with Visual Studio 2012, and can't find any "issues", but I do know I've done something wrong. I believe this is quite a unique situation, which might explain why I failed to find anything on the web about this.

How can I achieve this? I'd appreciated any help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting the result from the helper? If yes, try this instead:
$("#ContainerDIV").html(msg.d);